# main (div with all site) not working correctly

Tags: html, css

I want to do footer. I have main div there are all the page and out of main, there are div called footer. so my problem is the main are only 137px but the page are bigger. so the footer are in the top and not in the bottom. here is the html and the css i am using:

jsfiddle.net/gEgK9

what wrong? (look at `#footer` and `#main` at the css)

Comment: I don't get your question. But for those who do, here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gEgK9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the price for playing with `position:absolute` (or any other `position` value that's not `static`). Positioning will remove your element from the flow. This means, that all other elements in the same context with `position:static` will be rendered as if the element wasn't even there.

You would have to use `position:absolute;bottom:0;` in order to move the footer to the bottom. Don't forget that you'll have to calculate the margins and other positions to make sure that your footer won't collide with other elements. However, I do recommend you to think about your current situation and ask yourself whether the absolute positioning of your main content is really neccesary.

Comment: if i changing `#content` `position` from `absolute` to `static` it's messing up my page

Comment: As I already told you, you can use `position:absolute;bottom:0` on your page. However, your current CSS and markup is maybe a little bit complicated. Try to keep it simple and it should be much easier for you.

Comment: but i want to do the footer for all pages on my site. i dont know to height so i dont know where to place my footer.

Comment: @theShay: That's why positioning is always a hell of a beast. You could try to move your footer out of the `#main` div and apply a `margin` to `#main`. However, this won't work if `#main` contains any absolute positioned elements. Again, try to think of a way to achieve your desired results without positioning. This is possible and not that hard :).

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative units like % or em for heights of elements instead of px. Relative length units scales better between different rendering mediums. Check the details: https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_units.asp